# Varying CPU frequencies on Intel

Tags: x86, cpu, cpu-architecture, intel

I have an Intel server with specs:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                56
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-55
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    28
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 85
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6258R CPU @ 2.70GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2700.000
BogoMIPS:              5400.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
L3 cache:              39424K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,53,55
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

The system is **idle** and I inspect current frequencies of cores, I observe:

[image]

As you can see, one of the cores run at a way lower frequency than the rest. Actually a few cores run at lower frequencies (1000 MHz), but in the image you can see only one. What is the reason for this, is it expected? The cores with the lower frequency are not always the same ones, so I do not think there is a problem with specific cores.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @Rob: Good point, voted to migrate to superuser.  I wasn't thinking about it being off-topic when I wrote a quick-ish answer.  I guess serverfault could be appropriate since Xeon Gold is primarily a server CPU.

Comment: From my perspective this is clearly a software question -- what does the /proc/cpuinfo sysfile device driver choose to report for "cpu MHz"?  There is no unambiguously correct answer -- unless the hardware is configured to run at a fixed frequency all the time *and* none of the mechanisms that throttle frequency to limit power consumption or temperature are active.  Reporting a single frequency here is intrinsically confusing -- the interface presumably remains for legacy compatibility...

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: Linux `/proc/cpuinfo` reports the *current* frequency.  That seems like the most sane choice if they're going to limit it to one field, not like `lscpu` from util-linux showing a min MHz and max MHz field.  The file format has been extended some with new fields like `bugs`, `address sizes`, and several others, but I guess nobody's felt the need to add any new frequency-range fields.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The problem is that it is not possible to obtain the "current" frequency from user-space instructions.  Getting the frequency from each core requires entering the kernel, setting up a series of inter-processor interrupts to execute the RDMSR instruction(s) on the target cores, then returning the info to user space.   Crossing into the kernel to execute the required RDMSR instruction(s) is more than enough to cause the frequency to change.   May be better to deliver a one-minute running average?

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin: Does the `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy<CORE_NUMBER>/scaling_cur_freq` API optimize for the case where the frequency you're reading is the current core's?  If so, you could at least read your own frequency without IPIs, but still significant kernel overhead.  Using `perf stat` to count the `cycles` event over a time interval will give you the average frequency.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for CPU frequency to vary with load on a per-core basis, and reading the current CPU frequency creates load.

---

Could be the work of scheduling a kernel task onto that core to read its CPU info and format the text for a read system call from `/proc/cpuinfo` usually results in the freq jumping up from idle (presumably 1000 MHz) to its max non-turbo speed of 2700 MHz before it gets to reading the frequency. But sometimes that manages to happen fast, before the CPU frequency controller reacts to brief burst of load.

Hardware P-state management does react pretty fast by default, a feature of Skylake and newer Intel CPUs.

Lower-overhead ways to read the frequency of each core probably exist, e.g. reading `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq` for each CPU separately.  e.g. on my i7-6700k (Skylake "client"), where the hyperthreading layout enumerates one logical core of each physical core, then looping over the logical cores again:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq 
800015  
800003
800039
800099   # the first time we do anything on each physical core, it was at 800 MHz
4000000  # logical core 4 is physical core 0 again.  It's ramped to 4GHz now.
4000000
799384
800123

$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_cur_freq 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_cur_freq:807751
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy1/scaling_cur_freq:4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy2/scaling_cur_freq:800003
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy3/scaling_cur_freq:4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy4/scaling_cur_freq:4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy5/scaling_cur_freq:807804
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy6/scaling_cur_freq:4000000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy7/scaling_cur_freq:800102
```

grep has more overhead and gets more of the cores up to 4GHz.

---

You can set how aggressive hardware P-state management is by adjusting the energy-performance-preference (EPP).  `sudo sh -c 'for i in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy[0-9]*/energy_performance_preference;do echo balance_performance > "$i";done'`

Other settings available (listed in `energy_performance_available_preferences`) are `power` (least aggressive), `balance_power`, `balance_performance`, and `performance` (jump to max turbo pretty much right away when waking up, and less downclocking for a core that's memory-bound).  I find `balance_performance` is reasonable for my desktop to keep the fan quiet all the time, but it won't do turbo (to 4.2 GHz up from 4.0) unless I set `performance`.

To check your current EPP settings, `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy[0-9]*/energy_performance_preference` is a handy way to print out the filename and the setting.

On server CPUs, each core actually can change frequency independently, unlike on "client" CPUs where I think any/all non-sleeping cores run at the same clock speed, except maybe for turbo above the rated "sticker" frequency (which you can see in the CPUID model name).

See also

- https://en.wikichip.org/w/images/8/83/Intel_Architecture%2C_Code_Name_Skylake_Deep_Dive-_A_New_Architecture_to_Manage_Power_Performance_and_Energy_Efficiency.pdf re: Skylake's hardware power management, slides from an IDF2015 about the CPU design considerations.
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v6.0/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html - details on the sysfs tunables
- https://superuser.com/questions/1342706/cpu-throttling-energy-performance-preferences
- https://man.archlinux.org/man/x86_energy_perf_policy.8

---

As Dr. Bandwidth [pointed out in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75507023/varying-cpu-frequencies-on-intel?noredirect=1#comment133348645_75507023):

> The problem is that it is not possible to obtain the "current" frequency from user-space instructions. Getting the frequency from each core requires entering the kernel, setting up a series of inter-processor interrupts to execute the RDMSR instruction(s) on the target cores, then returning the info to user space. Crossing into the kernel to execute the required RDMSR instruction(s) is more than enough to cause the frequency to change. May be better to deliver a one-minute running average?

That's especially bad for the `/proc/cpuinfo` interface, which has to get the frequency of every CPU.
The `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy<CORE_NUMBER>/scaling_cur_freq` API could in theory optimize for the case where the core # you're reading is the core this task is already running on, which would avoid an IPI.

Using `perf stat` to count the `cycles` event over a time interval will give you the average frequency; that's a good suggestion.  But only if you're measuring a per-process time, so time (`task-clock`) only ticks while the clock is unhalted.  If you use `perf stat -a` to measure system-wide for a core across processes, time will tick while the clock doesn't.  So you could get a frequency way below `scaling_min_freq`.

---

#### `lcpu` will show you actual min/max frequencies

If you just want to know what frequency a core *can* clock down to at idle, or up to at max turbo, `lscpu` from `util-linux` is a good tool.  (There are multiple implementations of `lscpu` I think.)  Note the *CPU max MHz* and *CPU min MHz* entries.

```
lscpu
Architecture:           x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):       32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:        39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:           Little Endian
CPU(s):                 8
  On-line CPU(s) list:  0-7
Vendor ID:              GenuineIntel
  Model name:           Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
    CPU family:         6
    Model:              94
    Thread(s) per core: 2
    Core(s) per socket: 4
    Socket(s):          1
    Stepping:           3
    CPU(s) scaling MHz: 38%
    CPU max MHz:        4200.0000
    CPU min MHz:        800.0000
    BogoMIPS:           8003.30
    Flags:              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtop
                        ology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3
                        dnowprefetch cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat p
                        ln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Caches (sum of all):    
  L1d:                  128 KiB (4 instances)
  L1i:                  128 KiB (4 instances)
  L2:                   1 MiB (4 instances)
  L3:                   8 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                   
  NUMA node(s):         1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):    0-7
Vulnerabilities:        
  Itlb multihit:        KVM: Mitigation: VMX unsupported
  L1tf:                 Mitigation; PTE Inversion
 ...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "logical core 4 is physical core 0 again."? How did you figure that out?

Comment: @avernus: From looking at `/proc/cpuinfo` on my system: the `core id` field shows which physical core the Linux `processor` is from.  So I can see that processor 0 and 4 share core 0, processor 1 and 5 share core 1, etc. on my 4c8t machine.